# Django {{message}} not working in Javascript

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

I have a problem outputting a message in Django. I have Python which allows a user to enter a message and post it to Google App Engine. What I am aiming to do is to use the string in a comparison in Javascript to output a correct image.

I have the following in Javascript.

```
var img = document.createElement("img"); 
img.src = "images/150.png";
if ({{messages.get().message}} == "hello"){
  var src = document.getElementById("image1");
  src.appendChild(img);
}
```

I don't understand why `messages.get().message` isn't working. It gives me a parsing error for some reason. The Python code that is used to post the message in JSON is as follows:

```
endef getJSONMessages(callback):
messages = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Message ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 1")
strlist = ""
for message in messages:
    if len(strlist)>0:
        strlist += ',' + message.asJSONString()
    else:
        strlist = message.asJSONString()                  
if callback=='':
    return '[' + strlist + ']'
else:    
    return callback+'([' + strlist + ']);'
```

I would be very grateful for some help with this issue.

Comment: Does `{{ messages.get.message }}` work? You can’t have parentheses in Django template variable lookups, but Django [will automatically call methods](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/templates/#variables).

Comment: the app runs now .. but the image isnt being output

Comment: Mate thank you!! i cant beleive () was the problem..  it doens exactly work however . . i tested it with an output and it prints the message but the image is still not puting output

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){ 
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = "images/hello.png";
if({{messages.get.message}}== "hello"){
var src = document.getElementById("image1");
src.appendChild(img);
)}
this doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

try

```
var img = document.createElement("img"); 
img.src = "images/150.png";
if ("{{messages.get.message|escapejs}}" == "hello"){
  var src = document.getElementById("image1");
  src.appendChild(img);
}
```

There is no need for "messages.get()" in templates. "messages.get" wii do.

if you use

```
if(messages.get.message == "hello") { ... }
```

There will be no quotes around the message which will lead to syntax error.